Get Cromwell to increase disk space for task on GCP
It's possible to tell GCP to increase the amount of memory allocated to a VM when a run fails.  For example:
PAPIv2 {
  config {
    # Setup GCP to give more memory with each retry
    memory_retry_multiplier = 1.5

Is there a way to tell it to allocate more SSD space?  Because we're actually having more issues with running out of disk space than running out of memory

If you need to add additional space for the disk, try following this guide.
Note that for best practices, create a backup and shutdown the instance when doing this.
